# Windows store apps not displaying in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I installed windows 8 release preview. In my windows store i cant see many windows 8 apps like Skype.It displaying only 420 apps from starting. Not displaying any new apps. I dont know why ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please upgrade to the RTM version. You can download it from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/jj554510.aspx)

Comment: You can either download 90 days trial, or you can buy the full version here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/download-shop